# Is looping through the entityreference the correct way?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entityreference

I want to get all users that have a specific role to a list of usernames.

Is using .Include to include all the users, and going through the UsersReference
the best way to loop through all the users that are associated with the role?

I noticed I could not do a foreach(User user in role.Users) but UsersReference seem to work, but is that how it's supposed to be done? Going through the reference?

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            List<string> users = new List<string>();

            Role role = (from r in context.Roles.Include("Users")
                        where r.RoleName == roleName
                        select r).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (User user in role.UsersReference)
                users.Add(user.UserName);

            return users.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that your Role table has a Users property? I would think that it would name the navigation property Users, not UsersReference.  I don't use EF, but all the examples I've seen name the property after the table.   AFAIK it always implements IEnumerable so you should be able use it in a foreach.

If you have it set up right I think you only need:

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    return context.Roles
                  .Where( r => r.RoleName == roleName )
                  .SelectMany( r => r.Users )
                  .Select( u => u.UserName )
                  .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The Include method isn't necessary since the related User objects are being accessed inside of an active ObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your original foreach loop with **ToList**()

`foreach(var user in role.Users.ToList()) {...}`

Comment: This causes a third collection to be created where only IEnumerables are required. The `List<string> users`, the result of `.ToArray()` and the result of this `.ToList()`

Comment: The question was how to loop through all the users not the user names.

Comment: The question was: <quote>I want to get all users that have a specific role to a list of usernames.</quote> The code provided in the question is returning a `string[]` containing usernames of all users in the specified role. Even if looping through the users would be the assignment, the ToList is unneeded there.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `.ToArray()` helper instead

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    return (from role in context.Roles
            where role.RoleName == roleName
            from user in r.Users
            select user.UserName).ToArray();
}
```

Note that there's no need for `.Include("Users")` if you do it this way. Using `r.Users` in the query causes it to be in one query without the need for including it, because it's used in an active ObjectContext.

One a side note, I'm not sure what the method signature of this method is, but in this case `IEnumerable<string>` is probably a better fit than `string[]`, because you can adjust the implementation later without creating arrays from other types of collections.